# Why “Syracuse” in “Syracuse problem”

Tags: terminology

Is “Syracuse” in “Syracuse problem” (a variant name of Collatz conjecture) a reference to the city of Syracuse in Sicily, to one of several Syracuses in USA or something else (a person's name, for instance)?

Comment: To the (Math Dept at the) University of Syracuse (in New York State).

Comment: @Gerry: If that is true (and the French Wikipedia suggests it is) then it is an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"The name *Syracuse problem* was proposed by Hasse during a visit to Syracuse University [in Syracuse, New York] in the 1950s" according to Jeff Lagarias, on page 32 of his book about the problem.